# How to return zero instead of null from a subquery when a condition is not met

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data,

```
Id Value Tag
1   200   C
1   300   D
1   100   D
2   300   D
2   100   D
```

I want to sum up values of tags and deduct sum of D's from sum of C's. The below works fine if both tags are present for an id.

```
SELECT
    D.sumOfD - C.sumOfC as value,
FROM (
    SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(value),2),0) as 'sumOfD',Id
    FROM Reports exp WHERE exp.tag = 'D' 
) as D
JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(value),2),0) as 'sumOfC' ,Id
    FROM Reports exp WHERE exp.tag = 'C'
) as  C ON C.Id = D.Id
;
```

But if a tag is not available for an id either one of the subqueries will not return a value. In the above sample data there is only tag D for id 2 so the `on C.Id = D.Id` condition is failing. In this case i want zero to be returned.

Expected result

```
Id  Value
1   200 (300+100-200) 
2   400 (300+100-0) -- where 0 is the sum of values for tag C for id 2 which is zero
```

How can i do this? I am using **mysql **8.0.17****

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below - using `conditional aggregation`

```
select id, 
sum(case when Tag='D' then value else 0 end)-sum(case when Tag='C' then value else 0 end) as diff
from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include the desired result.

Comment: @Ayubx, this answer should satisfy your desire result

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation as suggested by Fahmi is a great idea, here is the query:

```
SELECT sums.D - sums.C as value
FROM (SELECT SUM(IF(tag = 'C', value, 0)) as C,
             SUM(IF(tag = 'D', value, 0)) as D
      FROM Reports
      GROUP BY id
     ) AS sums
```

---

The trick is in using a `GROUP BY` clause on your id to easily sum up your values, and the conditional aggregation for both tags to retrieve them in separate values.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method is:

```
select id, 
       sum(case when Tag = 'D' then value
                when Tag = 'C' then - value
                else 0 
           end) as diff
from tablename
group by id
```